# Impact of China and European Union on Canadian Inflation

Tags: inflation, monetary-policy, china, european-union, canada

I'm currently working on a project where I'm trying to determine the impact of the European Union and China on the Canadian economy, specifically, the inflation and policy rates for the next 2-3 years.

I'm not quite sure where to start with this since it's a very broad topic. I understand that Canada is in a state of excess demand, that there is a very tight labor market, and that there are global supply disruptions causing supply shortages. Because of this situation, there is rising inflation. To avoid entrenchment of inflation, the central bank is raising the policy rate and front-loading it in order to change inflation expectations and reduce the excess demand so that supply can catch up while inflation cools down. Now, global factors are playing a huge part in the issues that the Canadian economy is facing.

I'm wondering if there are any suggested data sources to look at in relation to the impact of the EU and China on the Canadian economic projection outlook and where I can find them. I have some readings, but since the topic is recent and many of the issues are current, many of the readings are a bit outdated. I'm looking for useful data and relevant research to try and do some sort of forecasting or projection, or at least put together something more concrete.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "impact of the EU"? Its trade? Its monetary policy? The effect of EU migration to Canada on the local labor market? The EU's effect on global culture and international law? It would be somewhat difficult to control for the existence of the EU countries, thus knowing what sort of effect you mean is likely essential.

Comment: @Giskard I meant the impact of EU and China on Candian monetary policy for the next 2-3 years. Trying to figure out what impacts effect Canadian monetary policy more is what I'm trying to study

Comment: Hi! You did not answer my question. What is the channel through which EU/China impact Canadian policy? See possible examples in comment above.

Comment: @Giskard Sorry about that, I guess I misread the question. The channels I'm going to look at include trade, supply chains, and their monetary policies. I'm not quite sure if I'm answering your question, the topic is relatively new to me and I'm trying to narrow it down and concentrate on the most important areas. I want to look at the main areas where they impact the Canadian projection outlook and analyze risks to the outlook through the impact of those channel areas. I'm still trying to work out what "those channel areas" include and how I could find good resources to narrow down the topic